# Possible to append another field to entries field title?

Tags: fieldtypes, entries-field

Does anyone know of a way to append another field to the entry title displayed in an entries field? I'd like to try and append an entry_version field to the title displayed so I get something like "Entry Title - v1" instead of just "Entry Title" when selecting related entries in a parent entry.

Comment: Are you wanting to use Craft Pro's built-in versioning number, or a separate version number field that you manually adjust?

Comment: A separate version number field is what I'd like to use.

Answer (score 1):

Under the Section's entry type settings, you can uncheck the "Show the Title Field" checkbox and set the title format to be something like:

```
`{title} - v{myVersionFieldHandle}`
```